# Create branch on state change of backlog item in Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, scrum

Is it possible to automatically create a branch when I drag a backlog item from "New" to "Approved" in Azure Devops?

Comment: You can only do it with Web Hooks.

Comment: This is a nice suggestion for Aggregator